# What could cause a Dapper cast to fail?

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper

I am using Dapper to execute a very simple query:

```
const string query =
          "SELECT measurement From Table;";
return connection.Query<Foo>(query);
```

with `foo` defined as follows:

```
public class Foo
{
    public object measurement { get; set; }
}
```

It works perfectly. If I inspect the resulting object, `Measurement` is a `double`.

However, if I explicitely type `Measurement` as a `double`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public double measurement { get; set; }
}
```

Dapper throws an exception:

> System.Data.DataException: 'Error parsing column 0
>   (measurement=4.64518928527832 - Double)'

Since typing as object works, it is not too annoying, but I would like to understand what causes this behavior.

Edit: Doing the same thing the old-fashionned way works perfectly fine with `measurement` typed as a `Double`

```
using (connection)
            {
                connection.Open();
                var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT measurement From Table;";
                Foo foo= new Foo();
                using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    foo.measurement = reader.GetDouble(0);
                }
            }
```

Edit2: Neither the stack trace

> Dapper.SqlMapper.ThrowDataException(Exception ex, Int32 index, IDataReader reader, Object value)

nor the inner exception

> System.InvalidCastException / "The specified cast is invalid"

are very useful.

Comment: Is `measurement` nullable in the DB?

Comment: What's the data type of the column in the database?

Comment: I hope it's not related to the decimal point.

Comment: @haim770 It is. (For what it is worth, none of the values returned by the query are null.) Setting the field the `double?` did not change anything.

Comment: @Maxime What's `measurement ` type in DB?

Comment: @ZoharPeled @D-Shih It's an Oracle `REAL`

Comment: You can try to use `float?` instead of `double`

Comment: Show the stack-trace and inner exceptions (if exists)

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find `REAL` in the [Oracle data type mappings page in Microsoft Docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-data-type-mappings). I'm guessing it can be either `float`, `decimal`, or simply an ugly double cast - `(double)(object)`. I wonder if you stumbled on a bug.

Comment: I have edited the question with the stack information.

I have tried a lot of types before thinking about `object`. double, float, single, decimal and their nullables don't work...

Comment: You could workaround it by adding an alias to the select statement and an object property, and have your double property simply return a cast to double of the object property - but it's ugly as hell and I would only use that as a last resort. Better ask Marc Gravell about it.

Comment: Try to register your own `ITypeHandler` for `double` using `SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(typeof(double), yourCustomDoubleHandlerInstance)`.

Comment: I have opened an issue: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/1090

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @haim770, I have been able to work around the issue, using the simplest TypeHandler possible:

```
public class DoubleTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<double>
{
    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, double value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override double Parse(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```